# How to set custom response status code in Slim Framework

Tags: angularjs, frameworks, slim

I use Angular JS, PHP and Slimframework on my new project.

I use promises in Angular JS but as you know if response status code return as 200 from the API, only the "success" part will work.

In Slimframework default response status code is 200 and all my requests return with status code 200. (if there is no errors it's normal)

But I want to make some validations and if validation fails I just want to change or set custom status codes in Slim framework. In this case I will be able to catch the problem in Angular JS with "error" code block

For example:

SlimFramework Part

```
$app->get('/getUserInformations/{user_id}', function(Request $request, Response $response){

    if(isLoggedIn()){

        //Do something and send an answer with status code 200

    }else{

        //Send some errors with status code 500 or something else

    }

});
```

Angular JS Part:

```
user.getUserInformations = function(){
    var defer = $q.defer();

    $http.get($rootScope.defaultApiPath + '/getUserInformations/1')
        .success(function(response){

            //if status code is 200 this means user logged in. Do something

            defer.resolve(response);
        })
        .error(function(error, status){

            // if status code is 500 this means not logged in. Show error message

            defer.reject(error);
        });

    return defer.promise;
};
```

In the docs of SlimFramework I found something like

```
$newResponse = $response->withStatus(302);

$data = array('name' => 'Rob', 'age' => 40);
$newResponse = $oldResponse->withJson($data, 201);
```

but I could't use them. Give me some errors that, method not found..

Shortly, my question is, how can I set custom status codes in slim framework..

Thank you in advance

Comment: return $response->withStatus(xxx);

Comment: Can you write it as an answer please. I want to set it as Correct Answer :) Thank you very much. 50 rows question,1 row answer. Great..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is...

```
return $response->withStatus(xxx);
```

http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/response.html#the-response-status